# MediaWiki and SimpleSAMLPHP authentication

Tags: php, mediawiki-extensions, simplesamlphp

I've been trying to integrate MediaWiki and SimpleSAMLPHP with both extensions available ([MultiAuthPlugin](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aMultiAuthPlugin) and [SAMLAuth](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aSAMLAuth)). However, I get the same error of 'State information lost' after trying to login via the Wiki in both cases.

I've tried to change the `store.type` to memcache and sql, but I still get the 'State information lost' error.

Was anyone out there able to integrate MediaWiki and SimpleSAMLPHP?

Answer (score 1):

Changing `store.type` should help.  Can you confirm that login does work when you use the *test authentication source* feature in SimpleSamlPhp?  If that doesn't work, your problem is not with a MediaWiki extension.

I wrote yet another SAML extension for MediaWiki; the ones already there did not solve my problem.  I am not saying that you will succeed with that one, but I can confirm that it works for me.  You can find it at https://github.com/yorn/mwSimpleSamlAuth/.